# ASP.NET MVC: ActionMethodSelector / ActionFilter (Attribute) naming conventions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

What do you think is the best naming convensions for ActionMethodSelector to differentiate from ActionFilter (Attributes).

I need an ActionMethodSelector that does the same as the AuthorizeAttribute-ActionFilter does, but how would you name that ActionMethodSelectorAttribue? (The implementation is not the issue)

Comment: Why not simply add 'Filter' as a suffix for your filters, and 'Attribute' on your attributes?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt follow the framework conventions, if you look at some of their implementations you will see in both cases they simply use an `Attribute` suffix.

```
AcceptVerbsAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
```

etc.

and

```
OutputCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
```

etc.

If you have no problem using framework attributes in this way, I don't see any reason you should do anything different for your own code.

Unless you want of course :D

Answer (score 0):

> What do you think is the best naming convensions for
>   ActionMethodSelector to differentiate from ActionFilter (Attributes).

The suffix:

- XXXActionMethodSelector
- XXXAttribute or XXXActionFilterAttribute

where XXX is obviously the function those classes are supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution I was already thinking, but the suffix is very long on looks ugly.
In the MVC framework itselfs, they don't make use of suffixes, so I was interested how they define the name of those attributes.
But there is no solution without the suffix, to differentiate the two aspects, without analyzing the attributes. (that is logically)

Answer (score 0):

```
XXXXSelectionAttribute
```

VS

```
XXXXFilterAttribute
```

It really doesn't matter, as long as you are consistent with your implementation, and the prefix or suffix adds a  clear picture to its intention.

IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it doesn't realy matter, but i very like clean code :) But for example how would you name an Authorize-ActionMethodSelectorAttribute? I often see the prefix/suffix "Required", "Only", "Allow", "Accept" for ActionMethodSelectorAttribute's. Maybe "RequiredAuthorization" would be a good name.

Comment: @ben Personally, I would keep them very granular and not join an Authorize attribute and ActionMethodSelectorAttribute.  But if that is the case, I would join specific words like XXXXAuthorizeSelectionAttribute, which indicates both an authorize and a selection capability.  Determine the ordering you like so everything is consistent (authorize before selection or vice versa).